# query sql en lenguaje raro con ajax

Tags: mysql, jquery, sql, ajax

Observen este codigo por favor.

```
<?
 1 1 @SelectTipo bsa "R" leq
    [[
      " select "
      " min(Anno) as minAnno " blk
      " from " blk
      " tabla" blk
      $sql_select_row ckd
        ]]
?>
```

Esto se encuentra en el archivo `pagina.st`

Es una especie de *php* a mas bajo nivel. Dentro te puedes encontrar *Javascript*, *html*, *JQuery*, ademas de este lenguaje raro con el que se trabaja en el backend. **Se hacen las *query* directamente dentro del documento**. Abro símbolo de *php*, meto el código que esta arriba y el servidor me está devolviendo información de la base de datos.

El servidor de aplicaciones fue construido como un módulo de servidor web *APACHE*.

El problema es que, cuando se utiliza, se te riega todo el código.

Estoy tratando de encontrar una manera de hacerlo con *jquery* pero mis conocimientos no llegan hasta allá. ¿Qué pudiera hacer con una consulta *sql* y *jquery*? Gracias.

Comment: Consultas AJAX a ficheros php que te devuelvan información o confirmaciones de un evento (por ejemplo para hacer una consulta de borrado y que te devuelva un 1 diciendo que se ha borrado o un 0 si no se ha borrado)

Comment: no consulto ficheros php todo ocurre dentro de la misma pagina y es manejado por este lenguaje.. tengo que introducir la query y manejar los datos @matahombres

Comment: No, no es exclusivamente un fichero php. AJAX carga cualquier fichero tipo de fichero sea aspx, js, php...  Si tiene implementación web, claro

Comment: Si puedo cargar .js, y tmb php que puedo hacer con esto..  el problema de hacer un php aparte puede ser la base de dato y el usuario y pass que se almacenan en una variabe aparte@matahombres

Comment: Jquery es un lenguaje de cliente por lo que no puedes conectarlo con lenguajes de servidor. Por eso te digo de AJAX ya que es la mejor forma de hacer una conexión entre ambos lenguajes.

Comment: En cuanto a el usuario y la pass puedes guardarlo en una constante del ```.htaccess``` ya que no cambian

Comment: si disculpa.. @matahombres con jquery me referia a ajax, ahora edito la pregunta.. eso es lo que quiero saber como puedo vincularlos hacer la consulta con ajax y luego mostrar los datos en mi html con jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es una consulta básica hecha con AJAX y JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'fichero.st',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {data1:'data1',data2:'data2'},
    success:function(output){
        //Los valores se pasan haciendo la función para mostrar datos. Por ejemplo, en el
        //caso de PHP echo o print_r()...
        //Código....
    }
});
```

**`url`**: Fichero linkeado
**`type`**: El método para pasar los datos, por POST o por GET
**`data`**: Pasas información
**`success`**: Cuando se finaliza de cargar todo el fichero

Si quieres hacer consultas más avanzadas de AJAX te recomiendo la [Documentación oficial](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), aunque también hay páginas en donde puedes hacer pruebas como [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

> He investigado un poco los ficheros `.st` y puede que sea un framework hecho con el lenguaje de programación **Smalltalk**

Comment: Gracias por tu atencion y el seguimiento de la pregunta @matahombres.. acepto tu respuesta.. mañana hare algo asi y luego lo subo estoy casi seguro que se puede.. saludos

Comment: y si tienes razon st es smaltalk, pero no es este caso es stweb algo raro... espero que haciendo las consultas asi me arregle un poco el codigo..